# Python remove brackets and apostrophe from dictionary key

Tags: python

So I am trying to use list comprehension to get the dictionary key for every value in my list.
It is currently printing: 10: ['even'] Where I want, 10: even.

```
   def display_number_report(start, stop):
       even_or_odd = {'odd': [],'even': []}
       number_list = [int(num) for num in range(start,stop+1)]
    
       for number in number_list:
           even_or_odd['odd'].append(number) if number%2!=0 else even_or_odd['even'].append(number)
       for num in number_list:
           print(f'{num}: {[key for key, value in even_or_odd.items() if num in value]}')

    display_number_report(10,20)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an `fstring` and format the data any way you need.

```
def report(start, stop):
    sel = ('even','odd')
    for i in range(start, stop+1):
        print(f'{i}:{sel[i%2]}')

report(10,20)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
def display_number_report(start, stop):
    even_or_odd = {'odd': [], 'even': []}
    number_list = [int(num) for num in range(start, stop + 1)]

    for number in number_list:
        even_or_odd['odd'].append(number) if number % 2 != 0 else even_or_odd['even'].append(number)
    
    for num in number_list:
        keys_for_num = [key for key, value in even_or_odd.items() if num in value]
        keys_str = ' '.join(keys_for_num)
        print(f'{num}: {keys_str}')

display_number_report(10, 20)
```